# Rails swagger gem documentation

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, swagger

I have a Rails project that is documented using Swagger Gem. Swagger is awesome, and now I want to send in response JSON an URL to documentation if was an error (only in development). Till now I identified that swagger doc url are builded like this:

```
$API_DOC_ROOT/controller/controller_action_method_sameID
```

How can I dynamically determine `someID` if only I know is controller, action and method?